# Перенаправление с чужой ссылки

Tags: javascript

На моём сайте http://ingsh.ucoz.ru я, воспользовавшись тегом iframe, поставил игровой автомат Fruit Cocktail, который идёт с другого сайта, при нажатии на кнопку EXIT он попадает на тот сайт, откуда идёт этот автомат. Как сделать через JavaScript так, чтобы при нажатии на эту самую EXIT пользователь попадал опять на мой сайт?

Answer (score 1):

Качать их флэшку - http://www.megajack.info/demo/game/fruitc/index.swf

И редактировать action scripts

JS тут не причем.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, а нет такого скрипта при котором на нажатии на область где находится кнопка EXIT, блокировалась или попадала опять на мой сайт?

Comment: Я о таком не слышал, мб и есть.

Comment: Если кнопка постоянно висит на экране и не двигается, можно поверх нее положить прозрачный div. Но тогда при нажатии флешка не поймет, что ей куда-то нажали.

Comment: Извините за мою глупость, а как такой див поставить чтобы именно на эту кнопку лёг?

Comment: `#yourDiv{width:__;height:__;position:absolute;top:__;left:__;opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)}`, вместо __ подставьте свои значения.

Comment: Эм, а давно поверх флэша дивы рисуются?

Comment: рисуются, а как давно я незнаю)

там z-index Забыли указать.

Comment: ИЕ параллельно, поверх селектов и флэша ничего не будет рисоваться, хоть бесконечность в з-индекс пиши. Когда-то давно подобное делал, пришлось мутить кнопку отдельным swf и его грузить поверх)

Comment: У меня ИЕ 10 рисует DIV поверх флеша... вот сайт www.hamzabon.ru в разделе видео верхнее меню имеет выпадающее под меню, и оно поверх flash плеера норм показывается, во всех броузах

Comment: Аэм, ну да) Я просто привык ие 6-7 считать живыми, в них посмотрите) У них SELECT и EMBED имеют статус "окно" и работают поверх сайта.

Comment: А вот top и left здесь это отступы от верхней и левой сторон?